# angularjs - Adding dependencies breaks data binding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am a newcomer to `angularjs` and am incredibly confused as to how `data-binding` and `dependency-injection` work.

To test if the code works, I created a test expression, `5+5`. It works if I don't inject dependencies inside the module, but doesn't if I inject one.

I am working with Ruby on Rails. Here is the example code

**Welcome.index.erb**

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
  <ul class="list-inline" ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <li><a ng-href="/api/auth/sign_in">Sign In</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="/api/auth/sign_up">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li>Help</li>
    <li>{{5+5}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
  angular.module("my-app", [])
    .controller("HomeCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.number = 1;
  });
</script>
```

This works, tested by the data-binding expression `{{5+5}}` evaluating to 10. However, if I add a dependency injection to my module

```
angular.module("my-app", ['ngRoute'])
   .controller("HomeCtrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.number = 1;
    });
   .controller("UserRegistrationsCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    });
   .controller("UserSessionsCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    });
   .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
       .when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'views/welcome/index.html.erb',
         controller: 'HomeCtrl'
       })
     .when('/sign_in', {
       templateUrl: 'views/user_sessions/new.html',
       controller: 'UserSessionsCtrl'
      })
     .when('/sign_up', {
       templateUrl: 'views/user_registrations/new.html',
       controller: 'UserRegistrationsCtrl'
      })
     .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
     });
   }]);
```

the data-binding looks like it gets broken, and the list item gets rendered as `{{5+5}}`.

**user_sessions/new.html**

```
<form ng-submit="submitLogin(loginForm)" role="form" ng-init="loginForm = {}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email"
           name="email"
           id="email"
           ng-model="loginForm.email"
           required="required"
           class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password"
           name="password"
           id="password"
           ng-model="loginForm.password"
           required="required"
           class="form-control">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

**user_registrations.html**

```
<form ng-submit="handleRegBtnClick()" role="form" ng-init="registrationForm = {}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email"
           name="email"
           id="email"
           ng-model="registrationForm.email"
           required="required"
           class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password"
           name="password"
           id="password"
           ng-model="registrationForm.password"
           required="required"
           class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label>
    <input type="password"
           name="password_confirmation"
           id="password_confirmation"
           ng-model="registrationForm.password_confirmation"
           required="required"
           class="form-control">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</button>
</form>
```

Not sure why the data-binding was broke. Any help will be appreciated.

**Update**

I went into the Console in Chrome Developer Tools, and ran a couple commands

```
var listElement = document.querySelector('ul')
listElement
=><ul class="list-inline" ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">...
listElement.controller();
=>TypeError: undefined is not a function
listElement.injector();
=>TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Here are the scripts I'm using

```
    <script src="/assets/jquery-7f1a72dc175eaa60be2e692ab9e6c8ef.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs-68ce8f5ee2895cae3d84a114fdb727e1.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-3dfec047bf3f975670c20b5e35a5f42e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular/angular-8bf873ad356fbb7267e223d5cac348f5.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-8bf873ad356fbb7267e223d5cac348f5.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-cookie/angular-cookie-79e90f9112d0e1bf9aede30a4b7f5d36.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-cookie-79e90f9112d0e1bf9aede30a4b7f5d36.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2d5fe21018866bf67cca9784e2ae95a9.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-bootstrap-2d5fe21018866bf67cca9784e2ae95a9.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-messages/angular-messages-f8b337aaacde7f3ee4d9fd590f36749a.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-messages-f8b337aaacde7f3ee4d9fd590f36749a.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-resource/angular-resource-79e25fff913ab31c097086ac463d7d41.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-resource-79e25fff913ab31c097086ac463d7d41.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router-1c9044ef4d22b7d3b266e72a34c275ea.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-ui-router-1c9044ef4d22b7d3b266e72a34c275ea.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils-895ce7dcab9d6b51db05d3816862b02c.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-ui-utils-895ce7dcab9d6b51db05d3816862b02c.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ng-token-auth/ng-token-auth-1e86f8812a656893f8b8ee6fe807290d.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ng-token-auth-1e86f8812a656893f8b8ee6fe807290d.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular/app-b06dbf3801b44bee508a1fea1255119d.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application-b2f074707bb9272eab9330966cfe5014.js?body=1"></script>
```

My application.js.coffee

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require bootstrap
#= require angular
#= require angular-cookie
#= require angular-bootstrap
#= require angular-messages
#= require angular-resource
#= require angular-ui-router
#= require angular-ui-utils
#= require ng-token-auth
#= require_tree
```

Comment: Can I do this with Chrome Developer Tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, you are placing semi-colons where you shouldn't be. You are breaking your method chains.

```
angular.module('my-app', ['ngRoute'])
   .controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
      ...
    })
   .controller('UserRegistrationsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      ...
    }])
   .controller('UserSessionsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      ...
    }])
   .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      ...
   }]);
```

I don't know that this would be your entire issue, but update your code accordingly, look at your console and report the errors coming out there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed the `)` after the controller name, so the braces should be closed now. By the way, where were the unneeded semicolons. I only put them at the end of controllers and statements. There shouldn't be a semicolon at the end of the controllers?

Comment: Correct - you had semi-colons after each controller was closed. You were trying to chain them together, which is a good design pattern, but were breaking the chain with the semi-colons. Think about it like a normal JS pattern, with each controller attached back to your angular.module().

Comment: As expected, the data-binding still doesn't work. Not sure how to debug angular, but I'll give it a shot and get back to you

Comment: I only ask this because you didn't include it in your example, but did you install ngRoute? See the spec: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.  When I run your code with ngRoute included I get 10, not {{5+5}} http://plnkr.co/edit/OprOhFtk9Rc60dk0ZeyF?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that `ngRoute` `angular-ui-router` were different things. This helped

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to my Gemfile and Assets. I had the following gem installed

```
gem "rails-assets-angular-ui-router"
```

I needed to add

```
gem "rails-assets-angular-route"
```

then add

```
#= require angular-route
```

to my `application.js.coffee` file